# Transistor circuit swap out motor for crude induction coil

Tags: transistors, coil, induction

I have a motor, which is the fan from inside a computer, is controlled by a BC237 transistor as in the diagram. The transistor is controlled by a signal from an Arduino. The signal comes on for 5 seconds and then off for two and this repeats. The motor then comes on for a few seconds and goes off as expected.

[image]

I replaced the motor with a crude coil of wire wrapped around a plastic pen cover inside which is a nail, with a magnet attached to the flat end. And the nail moves as expected when connected directly to a 3V battery. But not when the coil replaces the motor.

[image]

So why is the same thing not happening when I replace the motor for the coil?

I thought this has something to do with self inductance.

Is there anything I can do to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Based on what you wrote, current does flow in the coil you made and creates a magnetic field that moves a magnet. The BC237 is only rated for 100mA current, and it will have a voltage drop of 0.6V at 100mA, so the battery might be able to push more current via the coil. What is the coil resistance?

Comment: That only occurs when coil is connected directly to the 6v but when it is connected to the circuit with the transistor it does not work. Thanks

Comment: I tried to get a coil resistance but it seems to be 1 ohm. I don't think that is correct.

Comment: @ShaneG:  One ohm is probably wrong.  That's higher than I would expect for that simple coil.

Comment: @JRE thanks for your reply, I only know the basics of electronics. I disconnected the coil and measured its resistance with a multimeter. I think I will get a TIP120 it can handle up to 5A and 60V.